# Magento swatches still show up even after simple product for that color is disabled

Tags: php, magento

[Example](http://www.covalentactivewear.com/index.php/default/catalogsearch/result/?q=1010)

If you follow the link you can see that in the preview card there are 4 colors you can choose from, but once you click on the product, two of them disappeared. That's because we've disabled the color red/royal for this particular product.

How can I make it so that when I disable that particular color for a product it go away in the preview as well?